# creating / updating view using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create or update a view using stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROC Proc_Get_Ready_Weapons
AS
BEGIN

  IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = 'dbo.vwGetReadyWeapons')
  BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE VIEW dbo.vwGetReadyWeapons ... rest of view')
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dbo.vwGetReadyWeapons ... rest of view')
  END

  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated'  
END
```

But getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.
>   Warning: No rows were updated

Comment: There's a list of things that are cringe-worthy about this.  First, you're executing the same code regardless if the view exists.

Comment: Are you sure that checking `@@ROWCOUNT` is a valid test of whether the view was created or updated? I would probably use `TRY/CATCH` here instead.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE OR REPLACE` is not valid in SQL Server ([at least not yet](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127219/create-or-replace)).

Perhaps you meant:

```
EXEC('ALTER VIEW dbo. ...');
```

You also don't have a valid check. I think you meant:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.vwGetReadyWeapons'))
```

Comment: You have your conditions flipped, you are saying "if the view exists, create it, otherwise edit it." Sounds backwards, doesn't it? Try IF NOT EXISTS instead of IF EXISTS.