# Error creating view using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sql-view

I have following stored procedure which creates a view:

```
ALTER PROC Proc_Guards_By_Client
(
    @client_number INT,
    @client_name   NVARCHAR(16)
)
AS
 BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = 'vwGuardsByClients')
   BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE VIEW vwGuardsByClients
    AS
    SELECT TOP 1000 
      cgt.[guard_id],
      sg.first_name,
      sg.last_name,
      sg.ammunition_quantity    
      FROM [sws4].[dbo].[client_guard_tracking] cgt
      INNER JOIN CLIENTS c
      ON c.client_number = cgt.client_number
      INNER JOIN security_guard sg
      ON sg.guard_id = cgt.guard_id
      WHERE cgt.client_number = @client_number
      OR c.client_name = @client_name
    ')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      EXEC ('UPDATE VIEW vwGuardsByClients
      SELECT TOP 1000 
      cgt.[guard_id],
      sg.first_name,
      sg.last_name,
      sg.ammunition_quantity    
      FROM [sws4].[dbo].[client_guard_tracking] cgt
      INNER JOIN CLIENTS c
      ON c.client_number = cgt.client_number
      INNER JOIN security_guard sg
      ON sg.guard_id = cgt.guard_id
      WHERE cgt.client_number = @client_number
      OR c.client_name = @client_name
    ')
    END

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated'
 END
```

But when I execute it, I get:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 14
Must declare the scalar variable "@client_number".
```

Comment: Why do you use Dynamic SQL here?

Comment: this is requirement to create/update a view using stored procedure

Comment: I don't argue against SP. why dyn SQL? what do you achieve not using regular SQL?

Comment: @abatishchev did you try it? You can't call `CREATE VIEW` inside of a procedure.

Comment: This is STILL backwards. Your logic says: "If the view exists, create it! If it doesn't exist, edit it!" Also I have no idea where you learned the syntax "UPDATE VIEW" - it should be "ALTER VIEW."

Comment: "this is requirement to create/update a view using stored procedure" - that's not a requirement. That a broken piece of a solution that someone's decided is the "right" thing to do. We'd do a lot better if you told us what the original problem to solve was, rather than the problem with this broken solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the following will help. The problem is with using the parameters inline while building the statement

```
ALTER PROC Proc_Guards_By_Client
(
  @client_number         INT
  ,@client_name              NVARCHAR(16)
)
AS
BEGIN
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

  IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = 'vwGuardsByClients')
  BEGIN

  EXEC ('
  UPDATE VIEW vwGuardsByClients

SELECT TOP 1000 
  cgt.[guard_id],
  sg.first_name,
  sg.last_name,
  sg.ammunition_quantity    
  FROM [sws4].[dbo].[client_guard_tracking] cgt
  INNER JOIN CLIENTS c
  ON c.client_number = cgt.client_number
  INNER JOIN security_guard sg
  ON sg.guard_id = cgt.guard_id
  WHERE cgt.client_number = ' + cast(@client_number as varchar(10)) + 
  '  OR c.client_name = ''' + @client_name + '''
')
-- Here you missing one character '
  END
ELSE
BEGIN
   EXEC ('CREATE VIEW vwGuardsByClients
   AS
   SELECT TOP 1000 
  cgt.[guard_id],
  sg.first_name,
  sg.last_name,
  sg.ammunition_quantity    
  FROM [sws4].[dbo].[client_guard_tracking] cgt
  INNER JOIN CLIENTS c
  ON c.client_number = cgt.client_number
  INNER JOIN security_guard sg
  ON sg.guard_id = cgt.guard_id
  WHERE cgt.client_number = ' + cast(@client_number as varchar(10)) + 
  ' OR c.client_name = ''' + @client_name + '''
')
END

--SELECT * from vwGuardsByClients

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated'
```

END

Comment: This is STILL backwards. Your logic says: "If the view exists, create it! If it doesn't exist, edit it!" It also won't parse for a variety of reasons (not your fault, but you've just perpetuated them).

Answer (score 5):

There are still various issues. You've still got your logic backwards, [as you did yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466162/creating-updating-view-using-stored-procedure), when you acknowledged that it was backwards. How is it still wrong? Right now it says:

> If the view already exists:
>   
>       **Let's create it!**
>   
>   
> Otherwise, if the view doesn't already exist:
>   
>       **Let's edit it!**

The next problem is you use the syntax `UPDATE VIEW`. Yesterday you were trying to use `CREATE OR REPLACE`. Neither is valid. You need `ALTER VIEW`.

You're also still using `@@ROWCOUNT` to check for success. This isn't a valid check for creating or altering a view successfully (and it may not be appropriate for update/delete checks either, but that's a different issue). As I explained yesterday, you should be using `TRY/CATCH` for this.

Finally, you are trying to concatenate variables inside of `EXEC()` - and your appending of a string variable ignores the possibility that it includes apostrophes (`'`) which will break your query (there may be a SQL injection concern here as well). For this you should be using `sp_executeSQL`. In fact even better would be to not repeat all of that view code wastefully:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_Guards_By_Client
  @client_number  INT,
  @client_name    NVARCHAR(16)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N' VIEW dbo.vmGuardsByClient
    AS
      SELECT ... rest of view code ...
      WHERE cgt.client_number = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @client_number) + 
       ' OR c.client_name = ''' + REPLACE(@client_name, '''', '''''') + ''';';

  SET @sql = CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.vwGuardsByClients'))
    THEN N'ALTER' ELSE N'CREATE' + @sql;

  BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
  END CATCH
END
GO
```

Still, I have to ask. Why do you need to create a stored procedure for a specific view that isn't going to know whether the view already exists? Once you've created this view once, how will the `CREATE VIEW` portion of the code ever be executed again? Do all of your users have dbo/sa privileges, and this view is really in danger of being dropped at any time? Are you trying to create a view per client? If so you better think about adding the client name into the name of the view. In the current scenario you're going to replace the existing view every time a new client tries to run your code, then when the previous users select from the view they're going to be surprised that they no longer see their own data.